# How to implement Identity for group of records?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a table that contains a non primary key RequestID. When I do a bulkInsert, all the records must have **the same RequestID**. But If I do another BulkInsert, **the next inserted rows must have RequestID incremented** :

> NewRequestID = PreviousRequestID + 1

The only solution I found so far -and I don't like it by the way-, is to get the last record everytime before inserting the new records.

Why I dont like this approach ? because the database is supposed to be relationnel, which means there is "no specific order". Besides, I don't have primary keys or Dates to order with.

What is the best way to implement this?

(I've added c# tag because i am using EF. if there is an easy solution with EF)

Comment: Why can't you order them the way you want it and then get the last inserted record? That way, even though not relational, it is getting the job done for you?

Comment: Does it have to be an integer? Seems like you could use a `guid`/`uniqueidentifier` and just assign that to rows that belong together.

Comment: @Crazy Cucumber How can I order the records if there is no primary keys or Dates. Besides I do not usually relay on order based on primary key :(

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : Thanks I think I will go with the guids solution. I like this solution more than getting the last record. If there is no other solution i will go with it :)

Comment: @MehdiSouregi Couldn't you order by the requestID? Since that is exactly what you need ordered? `Order by PreviousRequestID desc` and `select top 1`. Then add 1 to it.

Comment: @CrazyCucumber, you are right, but I prefer the guid solution since there is only one operation invoked (inserting the new records) instead of two operations ( getting the last record and then doing the inserts). For cost puposes :)

Comment: Note that if you will have an index over that guid column - it's better to create sequential guid in database (in sql server for example there is NEWSEQUENTIALID() for that).

Comment: @Evk : you mean NEWSEQUENTIALID() as a default value ? because I want a group of records to have the same ID.

Comment: No, not as default value. Just instead of creating uuid on client (with Guid.NewGuid or something like that) - it might be better to create sequential guid in database ("select NEWSEQUENTIALID()" and then use that value when inserting all records). This might be important only if you have index over that column and insert a lot of data often.

Comment: @Evk When I do this select, I have an error : The NEWSEQUENTIALID() build-in function can only be used in a DEFAULT expression for a column of type 'uniqueidentifier'

Comment: Indeed, my bad, didn't know it only works when used as a default value for column. Well then you can forget about it :) If inserting non-sequential guids will ever become a performance problem, there are ways to generate them still, without NEWSEQUENTIALID. There is a request to support this (https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/Feedback/Details/732399) but they are not going to implement it in near future.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a number of different approaches:

- Are you guaranteed that your RequestID's are always incremented?  If so, you could query table for largest RequestID and that should represent the "last one inserted."
- You could track state somewhere in your application, but this is likely dangerous in scenarios where service fails/restarts (unless state is tracked externally).
- Assuming you have control over the schema, if you don't want to update the particular table schema you are speaking of, you could create another table to track the last RequestID used, and retrieve it from there (which would protect you against service restarts/failures).

Those are a few that come to mind.

UPDATE:

Assuming RequestID isn't a particular type of identifier, you could use timestamp - which will always be incremented when you do a new batch, however, I'm not sure if you needed it to always be incremented by exactly '1' which would preclude this approach.

Comment: Thanks for the solutions. Especially the third one, but it is not the best one. It just gives you a solution to keep in mind for future problems. And Like I said in the comments I'll go with the guids solution. I like it, because instead of doing two database call (selecting and inserting), you only do a single call. Easy to implement and does not cost memory

Comment: Not sure if you saw my last one, but that suggested time stamp.  That has the benefit over GUID because you'll actually get implied order for free and you don't have an extra call, just like GUID.